# I can't decide what to buy for fixing my wifi signal

Tags: ieee-802.11

I have a broadband 2.4Ghz modem, and I'm facing signal issues.
Will it be sorted out if I buy a 5Ghz wifi repeater and connect it to the 2.4Ghz modem? Or do I need to buy something different?
I searched a lot but couldn't reach a fulfilling answer.

Comment: Sadly home networking is off topic here. But briefly, you ought to spend time to identify the problem. Otherwise you are probably wasting your money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific product recommendations are off topic (because they get obsolete).  Consumer gear is also off topic.

It's not clear what device you have.  It is a "modem" so it has a WAN connection (DSL or cable) on one end.  It also provides 2.4-GHz only WiFi.  If that is true, then it is very low-cost, or ancient.  5GHz WiFi has been common for a long time.  Since it has WiFi in addition to the WAN connection, it is presumably a combination modem/router.

For a small house (<1500 ft^2), one good modern combination cable modem / router / WiFi device is generally fine.   For a larger house, I've found the new WiFi mesh kits to be good.  I recently purchased a 2-unit kit: a base station for connecting to the modem, plus one extension unit for the "far" end of the house.

For the small house I would *not* daisy chain a new router/modem to the existing ancient/cheap one.  I would replace it with a new combination modem/router/WiFi unit.  That generally requires reactivating with the provider so make sure you know your username/password.  Make sure to check your provider's "modem compatibility list".

For the large house, you could plug the mesh base station into your old router/modem ethernet port.  Ideally you would turn off the wifi in the old base station to minimize interference.  Given unlimited budget, I would prefer to replace the ancient modem, but budget constraints are real and its better to buy only one thing at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate the time you spent typing your answer.